# Подскажите как убрать кнопку "Язык" из поля что ниже содержимого на каждой страничке оставив кнопки языка в шапке

Tags: drupal

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый день!
Кто сталкивался с мултиязычностью на Drupal 7 ? 
Подскажите как убрать кнопку с языком из тела страницы с материалом, и оставить только в шапке.

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашел решение: Главная » Администрирование » Конфигурация » Регион и язык » Multilingual settings » NODE OPTIONS необходимо поставить галочку "Hide content translation links"